# Using powershell to delete the middle of a string

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I have a text file which contains the text

```
DATA collate UNKNOWN null,
or 
DATA collate UNKNOWN not null,
```

I need to delete collate and the unknown from the text file, I'm currently thinking the       -replace with some form of regex is the way to go in some way shape or form, but I can't figure out how to keep the null or not null.

Also note that every line in the file does not contain collate and Unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `UNKNOWN` is a placeholder for any number of characters?

Then try

```
$result = $subject -creplace 'DATA collate .*?((?:not )?null,)', 'DATA $1'
```